Opendaylight Restconf always answers 401
I did install opendaylight 0.19.2 with odl-restconf-nb to access via restconf on the northbound interface.
I try to send Get/Post request but it doesn't matter what type would I like to send I always get 401 as the answer.
I tried with curl and postman too, but same.
curl -u admin:admin http://$VM-IP:8181/restconf/operational/network-topology
I should get not an 401 answer for this call, even if I didn't added the Content-Type=application/xml Accept=application/xml flags.
But if I add nothing changes.
I'm desparate now, tried different versions of the controller but I get same.

Have you tried following the OpenDaylight NETCONF user guide?
It seems like you're attempting to use the /restconf/ endpoint (draft-bierman-netconf-restconf-02) instead of /rests/ URI (RFC8040).
The draft-bierman-netconf-restconf-02 implementation is no longer available in recent OpenDaylight releases.
For more details, you can refer to the following links:
draft-bierman vs. RFC8040
ONAP RESTCONF Migration

In my experience, the 401 message is generated when ODL finds an instruction that cannot process. For the example above, you may want to try:
curl -u admin:admin -X GET http://$VM_IP:8181/rests/data/network-topology:network-topology


The proposed answer appears to be to add -X GET to the command-line. I notice that the original response says, _ I try to send Get/Post request but it doesn't matter_. It would be good to be explicit about how the answer proposes to fix the command-line.
